# asp.net ValidationSummary and User Controls

Tags: asp.net, validation, validationsummary

I'm doing a webform in .Net 3.5. I have a number of user controls on a page that have validation (mostly required fields) in the user controls. On the main page I have a validation summary.

The validation summary shows the errors correctly. The problem is when there's a field in a user control that is required and I fill it in, the validation message goes away but it still shows in the validation summary.

The code for the validation summary is:

```
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary" runat="server" ShowSummary="true"
        DisplayMode="BulletList" CssClass="RequiredMessage" EnableClientScript="true"
        HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:" />
```

The validation works correctly just appears as if in a user object it doesn't update unless a postback is done.

Is there something I need to add to the user object?

TIA - Jeff.

Comment: You say that 'validationsummary' doesnt change even when you fill in a textbox for example? So does this happen even after you click the submit button?

Comment: If you click a button, or go through a field that has autopostback turned on, it's then correct.

Comment: Post the entire code here

Comment: OK - I wonder if I'm missing something. I assume that because the validation disappears once the error is fixed (without a submit), does the validation summary go away also (without a submit) ? Or does it only go away on a submit?

Comment: After a little research, looks like validationsummary does not go away without a postback.You need to write some javascript to make it go away once there are no more validation errors on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the same ValidationGroup (for example ValidationGroup="MyGroup") to all validation controls and ValidationSummary control.

PS. Please show the validation controls code.

Comment: Do you mean the code that's in the user control? It's a normal RequiredFieldValidator control. If you want it, I can put in the entire code for the user control.